# Grab data from one cell and write it to a json string in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am a Pandas newbie and I want to create a json summary of the data I have in a csv file. This json summary will populate the last column of my csv and is named "Holder". My csv file follows:

```
pk,Pure_Math,Pure_Math_Notes,Applied_Math,Applied_Math_Notes,Stats,Stats_Notes,Grammar,Grammar_Notes,Lit,Lit_Notes,Holder
1,0,,-1,Good student,0,,-1,Gr8 potential,0,,
2,-1,Fair,0,,0,,0,,-1,Hard worker,
3,-1,Brilliant,-1,Masters material,-1,Outstanding,0,,0,,
```

For each course, I want to grab all the data in a row and append it to the last column. My code follows

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas.io.data
import numpy as np
import json

    df = pd.read_csv('c:\censored.csv')

    col_array = np.array([
            ["Pure_Math", "Pure_Math_Notes", "Applied_Math", "Applied_Math_Notes", "Stats", "Stats_Notes"],
            ["Grammar", "Grammar_Notes", "Lit", "Lit_Notes"]
    ])

    a = ''
    b = ''
    c = ''

    df.fillna('')
    df.Holder = ''
    count = 0
    substrategy = 0
    for cat in col_array:
        count += 1
        for innercat in cat:        
            if "_Notes" in innercat:
                b = df[innercat]
                #print b
                continue
            substrategy += 1
            c = count
            a = substrategy
            odata = {}
            odata['did'] = a
            odata['id'] = a        
            odata['data'] = {}
            #odata['data']['notes'] = b
            odata['data']['notes'] = ''
            odata['data']['coursecode'] = a
            odata['data']['department'] = c
            df.loc[df[innercat] == -1, 'Holder'] += json.dumps(odata) + ', '
```

The code works fine until I uncomment the line

```
#odata['data']['notes'] = b
```

I get a `TypeError: 0          NaN` error. I believe that encountering a NaN during the json conversion causes pandas to fail. What can I do to correct this?
I have tried setting all NaN values to a blank space, but it's not working.

Comment: Could you give us an example of what your final output should look like?

Comment: Your code works perfectly here, copied and pasted. Uncommented the line and used your data too. Tested on: python 3.4.3 + numpy 1.11.0 + pandas 0.18.0